# Order products by distance with geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I have two models : Product and Location, and Location belongs_to Product.

I use the geocoder gem, and I want to do just as in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder) but I can't figure it out...

Part of my **app/views/products/index.html.erb**

```rb
<% @products.each do |p| %>
   <%= p.name %>
   <%= @current_location.distance_to(p.location) %>
<% end %>
```

Part of my **app/controllers/products_controller.rb**

```rb
def index
  @current_location = params[:search]
  if @current_location
    @products = Product.with(:location).near(@current_location, order: :distance).paginate(page: params[:page])
  else
    @products = Product.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

But it renders this :

```rb
undefined method `with' for ....
```

Can you help me order my product by distance with geocoder ?

Comment: Why do you call `with(:location)`? This call is the source of your error.

Comment: Because if I do `Product.near(...` it tells me `undefined method 'near' for...`. The problem is that in railscast, the locations are directly ordered and shown, and in my app, the product.locations are ordered, and the products are shown.